# Possible Unhandled promise rejection TypeError: Network request failed, cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Tags: react-native

Recently started learning react-native and I'm following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rcXyN_cfGY8) tutorial on youtube, I'm trying to fetch flags and country codes from some websites api but I'm getting an error saying

> Possible Unhandled promise rejection  TypeError: Network request
> failed, cannot read property 'map' of undefined

```
import {
    View,
    Text,
    TouchableOpacity,
    TouchableNativeFeedback,
    Image,
    TextInput,
    Modal,
    FlatList,
    KeyboardAvoidingView,
    ScrollView
} from "react-native";
import React from "react";
import LinearGradient from "react-native-linear-gradient";

import { COLORS, SIZES, FONTS, icons, images } from "../constants"

const SignUp = () => {

    const [showPassword, setShowPassword] = React.useState(false);

    const [areas, setAreas] = React.useState([]);
    const [selectedArea, setSelectedArea] = React.useState(null);
    const [modalVisible, setModalVisible] = React.useState(false);

    React.useEffect(() => {
        fetch("https://restcountries.eu/rest/v3.1/all")
            .then(response => response.json())
            .catch(err => {
                console.log(err);
            })
            .then((data) => {
                let areaData = data.map(item => {
                    return {
                        code: item.alpha2Code,
                        name: item.name,
                        callingCode: `+${item.callingCodes[0]}`,
                        flag: `https://countryflagsapi.com/png/${item.alpha2code}`
                    }
                }).catch(err => {
                    console.log(err);
                });

                setAreas(areaData)

                if (areaData.length > 0) {
                    let defaultData = areaData.filter(a => a.code == "US")

                    if (defaultData.length > 0) {
                        setSelectedArea(defaultData[0])
                    }
                }
            })
    }, [])

    function renderHeader() {
        return (
            <TouchableOpacity
                style={{
                    flexDirection: "row",
                    alignItems: "center",
                    marginTop: SIZES.padding * 2,
                    paddingHorizontal: SIZES.padding * 2
                }}
                onPress={() => console.log("SignUp")}
            >
                <Image
                    source={icons.back}
                    resizeMode="contain"
                    style={{
                        width: 20,
                        height: 20,
                        tintColor: COLORS.white
                    }}
                />

                <Text
                    style={{ marginLeft: SIZES.padding * 1.5, color: COLORS.white, ...FONTS.h4 }}
                >Sign Up</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        )
    }

    function renderLogo() {
        return (
            <View
                style={{
                    marginTop: SIZES.padding * 5,
                    height: 100,
                    alignItems: 'center',
                    justifyContent: 'center'
                }}
            >
                <Image
                    source={images.wallieLogo}
                    resizeMode="contain"
                    style={{
                        width: "60%"
                    }}
                />
            </View>
        )
    }

    function renderForm() {
        return (
            <View
                style={{
                    marginTop: SIZES.padding * 3,
                    marginHorizontal: SIZES.padding * 3,
                }}
            >
                {/* Full Name */}
                <View
                    style={{
                        marginTop: SIZES.padding * 3,
                    }}
                >
                    <Text
                        style={{
                            color: COLORS.lightGreen, ...FONTS.body3
                        }}
                    >Full Name</Text>
                    <TextInput
                        style={{
                            marginVertical: SIZES.padding,
                            borderBottomColor: COLORS.white,
                            borderBottomWidth: 1,
                            height: 40,
                            color: COLORS.white,
                            ...FONTS.body3
                        }}
                        placeholder="Enter Full Name"
                        placeholderTextColor={COLORS.white}
                        selectionColor={COLORS.white}
                    />

                    {/* Phone Number */}
                    <View style={{ marginTop: SIZES.padding * 2 }}>
                        <Text style={{ color: COLORS.lightGreen, ...FONTS.body3 }}>Phone Number</Text>

                        <View style={{ flexDirection: "row" }}>
                            {/* Country Code */}
                            <TouchableOpacity
                                style={{
                                    width: 100,
                                    height: 50,
                                    marginHorizontal: 5,
                                    borderBottomColor: COLORS.white,
                                    borderBottomWidth: 1,
                                    flexDirection: "row",
                                    ...FONTS.body2
                                }}
                                onPress={() => console.log("Show Modal")}
                            >
                                <View style={{ justifyContent: "center" }}>
                                    <Image
                                        source={icons.down}
                                        style={{
                                            width: 10,
                                            height: 10,
                                            tintColor: COLORS.white,
                                        }}
                                    />
                                </View>
                                <View style={{ justifyContent: "center", marginLeft: 7 }}>
                                    <Image
                                        source={{ uri: selectedArea?.flag }}
                                        resizeMode="contain"
                                        style={{
                                            width: 30,
                                            height: 30
                                        }}
                                    />
                                </View>
                                <View style={{ justifyContent: "center", marginLeft: 7 }}>
                                    <Text style={{ color: COLORS.white, ...FONTS.body3 }}>{selectedArea?.callingCode}</Text>
                                </View>
                            </TouchableOpacity>

                            {/* Phone Number Input */}
                            <TextInput
                                style={{
                                    flex: 1,
                                    marginVertical: SIZES.padding,
                                    borderBottomColor: COLORS.white,
                                    borderBottomWidth: 1,
                                    height: 40,
                                    color: COLORS.white,
                                    ...FONTS.body3
                                }}
                                placeholder="Enter Phone Number"
                                placeholderTextColor={COLORS.white}
                                selectionColor={COLORS.white}
                            />
                        </View>
                    </View>

                    {/* Password */}
                    <View style={{ marginTop: SIZES.padding * 2 }}>
                        <Text
                            style={{
                                color: COLORS.lightGreen,
                                ...FONTS.body3
                            }}
                        >Password</Text>
                        <TextInput
                            style={{
                                marginVertical: SIZES.padding,
                                borderBottomColor: COLORS.white,
                                borderBottomWidth: 1,
                                height: 40,
                                color: COLORS.white,
                                ...FONTS.body3
                            }}
                            placeholder="Enter Password"
                            placeholderTextColor={COLORS.white}
                            selectionColor={COLORS.white}
                            secureTextEntry={!showPassword}
                        />
                        <TouchableOpacity
                            style={{
                                position: "absolute",
                                right: 0,
                                bottom: 10,
                                height: 30,
                                width: 30
                            }}
                            onPress={() => setShowPassword(!showPassword)}
                        >
                            <Image
                                source={showPassword ? icons.disable_eye : icons.eye}
                                style={{
                                    height: 20,
                                    width: 20,
                                    tintColor: COLORS.white
                                }}
                            />
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                    </View>
                </View>
            </View>
        )
    }

    function renderButton() {
        return (
            <View style={{ margin: SIZES.padding * 3 }}>
                <TouchableOpacity
                    style={{
                        height: 60,
                        backgroundColor: COLORS.black,
                        borderRadius: SIZES.radius / 1.5,
                        alignItems: "center",
                        justifyContent: "center"
                    }}
                    onPress={() => console.log("Let's Go")}
                >
                    <Text style={{ color: COLORS.white, ...FONTS.h3 }}>Continue</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>

            </View>
        )
    }

    return (
        <KeyboardAvoidingView
            behavior={Platform.OS === "ios" ? "padding" : null}
            style={{ flex: 1 }}
        >
            <LinearGradient
                colors={[COLORS.lime, COLORS.emerald]}
                style={{ flex: 1 }}
            >
                <ScrollView>
                    {renderHeader()}
                    {renderLogo()}
                    {renderForm()}
                    {renderButton()}
                </ScrollView>
            </LinearGradient>
        </KeyboardAvoidingView>
    )
}

export default SignUp;
```

Saw an old post regarding this issue but the solution of adding catch(err didn't work please any suggestions

Comment: You add .catch at the end of the last .then not inbetween them. https://javascript.info/promise-error-handling

Comment: Second issue is that the link is dead so you cannot get any data from it.

Comment: thank you I found my error was from the links the data fetched and the values assigned did not match, the alpha2code and callingCodes are for v2 while I am using the v3 and the link was changed to .com

Answer (score 0):

The problem you faced mainly occurs in the `fetch()` inside `useEffect()`.

To handle the any potential errors in function, we will use `catch()` as [@caslawter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73774668/possible-unhandled-promise-rejection-typeerror-network-request-failed-cannot-r#comment130273635_73774668) mentioned.

```
fetch("https://restcountries.eu/rest/v3.1/all")
.then(response => response.json())
.then((data) => {
    //... Do what you want after fetch data
})
.catch(err => {
    //Any error occurs in json parsing or after fetching data will jump to here
    console.log(err);
})
```

Also, please make sure your data is not undefined before you apply 'map' function to it.

Comment: I used the catch at the end of the last .then but the error still appear but this time there is not error regarding the map property just the unhandled promise rejection and network request failed

Comment: Thank you I found where the error was from